# Disabling screenupdating in VBA also removes the background in the DisplayBar

Tags: excel, vba

When you use `application.screenupdating = False` in VBA, the `Application.StatusBar` at the bottom no longer has a grey background. In this case it becomes green when a macro runs, and grey text on green is difficult to read. Is there a way to resolve this at all?

Comment: Please teach me how to change the colour of the status bar field. It shouldn't be related to ScreenUpdating. Avoid Application.StatusBar = True. Use Application.Statusbar = False to clear it or Application.Statusbar = "Text" to show a text.

Comment: @Variatus Sorry, maybe I should have been clearer - what seems to happen is that the grey bar entirely gets removed, so the grey gradient you see in the background vanishes, and instead the standard Excel green appears. I don't want that to happen - I want a grey background all the time. I'm starting to think that perhaps there's a bit of code I have somewhere that's causing this somehow.

Comment: That's exactly what I think, too.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out of you just add a `application.screenupdating=False` just before the `application.StatusBar` comment, it works fine. Seems like the best workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To solution above didn't work for me adding Application.ScreenUpdating = True before Application.StatusBar and Application.ScreenUpdating = False  after, worked form me

exeple :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = "Mise à jour des formats"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```